# Images not displaying in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

I am new in laravel(using version 7),I downloaded existing project and trying to run in my local system,Project is working fine but unable to display any image,I am getting following line in front of images,How can i fix this ?,For example in image tag i am getting

```
/storage/photos/1/Category/mini-banner1.jpg
```

In img tag i am getting following code

```
<img src="/storage/photos/1/Category/mini-banner1.jpg" alt="/storage/photos/1/Category/mini-banner1.jpg">
```

Comment: First run php artisan storage:link .if it showing already created then delete symblink folder from public folder and run php artisan storage:link again 

and html change 

<img src="{{asset('photos/1/Category/mini-banner1.jpg)}}" alt="{{asset('photos/1/Category/mini-banner1.jpg')}}">

Comment: are you sure the path is right? can you show the the directory structure of `public` and `storage`

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

*Static Image Path*

```
<img alt="no-image" class="img-fluid" src="{{asset('uploads/default/no-image.png')}}">
```

*Dynamic Image Path*

```
<img  class="img-fluid" src="{{asset('uploads/banner/'.$value->vImage)}}">
```

Answer (score -1):

execute this cmd in your terminal

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: still facing same problem